# Return count in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure to return a count. But I got a null value. Can anybody tell me where is the problem in my stored procedure.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateUser]
@UserName varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Num_of_User int output

AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT @Num_of_user =COUNT(*) 
    FROM login
   WHERE username = @UserName 
     AND pw = @Password

  RETURN

END
```

Comment: How are you trying to read that value?

Comment: @BenCr tells you how to get the count as a return value, or to use the output parameter you defined as part of your stored procedure. @atbebtg tells you how to get the count as a resultset.

Answer (score 11):

you are setting the value into the variable @num_of_user.  add select @num_of_user  after the query

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateUser]
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50),
    @Num_of_User int output

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SELECT @Num_of_user =COUNT(*) 
         FROM login
         WHERE username=@UserName AND pw=@Password

     SELECT @Num_of_user
return
END
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually return the count, it's an output parameter.

Either change your sproc to return @num_of_user or check the output parameter instead of the return value.

Comment: My code is checking the output parameter but it is null. Now I modified the sproc as {ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateUser]
 @UserName varchar(50),
 @Password varchar(50),
 @Num_of_User int output
 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT COUNT(*) as Num_of_user
         FROM login
         WHERE username=@UserName AND pw=@Password

END}  and the num_of_user is still null. I am not good at SProc. Please help.

Comment: Without a full copy of the calling code and your DB I don't know how I can help. Have you tested your SPROC from SQL Server Management Studio? Is it a problem with the data or the calling code?

Answer (score 1):

Procedures and functions in SQL server are a bit confusing to me, since a procedure can also return a value. However, you can achieve what you wish by removing the output parameter @Num_of_user and replacing

```
SELECT @Num_of_user =COUNT(*) 
    FROM login
   WHERE username = @UserName 
     AND pw = @Password
```

with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM login
   WHERE username = @UserName 
     AND pw = @Password
```

The last select statement is always returned from a PROCEDURE in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the isnull. Select count(*) always return a non-null value. You can even issue a

```
select count(*) from anytable where 1=2
```

and you'll get a 0, not a null. I think that your problem arrives when you exec the sp. You may be lacking the 'output' keyword next to the @Num_of_User. Your call should be something like

```
declare @outNum int 
exec ValidateUser 'some', 'wrong', @outNum output
print @outNum
```

Notice the 'output' keyword to the right of the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Just another method but outside the Stored Procedure a simple 
`SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` 
can work to get the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when it returned null; try to use parenthesis:

```
SELECT @Num_of_user = ( COUNT(*) 
    FROM login
   WHERE username = @UserName 
     AND pw = @Password )
```