# Return ROW COUNT from stored procedure in MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How can I return the row count from the query in this stored procedure? I have been trying to implement solutions found on other stack overflow posts that are similar but each result in the output being the columns with the count for each individual record. (ie, one column will output 1,1,1,1,1 for every row...)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_proc ()
BEGIN
   SET @start_date = LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
   SET @end_date = LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

   SELECT users.*, count(DISTINCT mr_rev.id) AS prev_reg
   FROM users
        INNER JOIN gr_user_group
           ON     gr_user_group.user_id = wp_users.ID
              AND gr_user_group.group_id != 22
              AND gr_user_group.group_id = 5
        INNER JOIN usermeta ON users.ID = usermeta.user_id
        INNER JOIN mr_rev
           ON users.ID = mr_rev.users_id AND mr_rev.mr_rev_types_id = 2
        INNER JOIN mr_rev mrr
           ON     users.ID = mrr.users_id
              AND mrr.mr_rev_types_id = 2
              AND mrr.created_on >= @start_date
              AND mrr.created_on <= @end_date
        INNER JOIN mr_revs_meta
           ON     mr_rev.id = mr_revs_meta.mr_rev_id
              AND mr_revs_meta.meta_value > @end_date
              AND mr_revs_meta.created_at < @end_date
   WHERE users.ID NOT IN ('101', '102')
   GROUP BY users.ID
   HAVING prev_reg > 15;
END;
```

Is there an efficient way to return the total row count?

EDIT:  [Return count in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144584/return-count-in-stored-procedure) one of the posts I unsuccessfully implemented.

Comment: if you are in sql server @@rowcount will give output

Comment: yeah I am coming from SQL Server, but am now primarily using MySQL, started about two weeks ago! This post was regarding mysql as tagged above.

Comment: I am talking in the context of this question, is it running on SQL Server or MysQL?

Comment: MySQL is what is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the query in an another select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT users.*, count(DISTINCT mr_rev.id) AS prev_reg
       FROM users
            INNER JOIN gr_user_group
               ON     gr_user_group.user_id = wp_users.ID
                  AND gr_user_group.group_id != 22
                  AND gr_user_group.group_id = 5
            INNER JOIN usermeta ON users.ID = usermeta.user_id
            INNER JOIN mr_rev
               ON users.ID = mr_rev.users_id AND mr_rev.mr_rev_types_id = 2
            INNER JOIN mr_rev mrr
               ON     users.ID = mrr.users_id
                  AND mrr.mr_rev_types_id = 2
                  AND mrr.created_on >= @start_date
                  AND mrr.created_on <= @end_date
            INNER JOIN mr_revs_meta
               ON     mr_rev.id = mr_revs_meta.mr_rev_id
                  AND mr_revs_meta.meta_value > @end_date
                  AND mr_revs_meta.created_at < @end_date
       WHERE users.ID NOT IN ('101', '102')
       GROUP BY users.ID
       HAVING prev_reg > 15 ) a;
```

Comment: this worked! thanks a lot! is this the most efficient way (out of curiosity)?

Comment: There might be a better way to do it but the question does not have enough information for me to answer this. Anway, if you think this answer has solved your problem then would you mind accepting this answer?